# How to add distance between nodes in tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new as a tikz user and I face huge issues to do what I actually want to do ...
I have to draw a graph which is parameterized by a value. For example, it means that the number of node at the second node level is between 0 and a value `X`. For this reason, I cannot draw the full graph, but I have to ellipse some part using `\ldots` for example.

To do that, I am using `arrows` and `automata` tikz libraries but I have an issue at the second node level : the 4 node I want to draw are overlaid... 
Here is the source:

```
 \documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,shapes}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5cm,sibling distance=50cm,
    semithick]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[
        rounded rectangle,
        fill=red,
        draw=none,
        text=white,
        align=center,
        inner sep=1pt,
        text width=9.5em,
    ]
    \tikzstyle{kernel} = [
        inner sep=1pt,
        node font=\itshape \small,
    ]

    \node[state]    (A)                     {$A(0:DIM\_X, 0)$};
    \node[state]    (B) [below left of=A]   {$A(1, 1)$};
    \node[state]    (C) [below right of= A] {$A(DIM\_X-2, 1)$};
    \node[state]    (D) [below of=B]        {$A(1, 2)$};
    \node[state]    (E) [right of=D]        {$A(2, 2)$};
    \node[state]    (F) [below of=C]        {$A(DIM\_X-2, 2)$};
    \node[state]    (G) [left  of=F]        {$A(DIM\_X-3, 2)$};


    \path (A)   edge node[kernel,swap]      {S(1, 1)}       (B)
                edge node[kernel]   {S(DIM\_X-2, 1)}    (C)
    ;
    \path (B)   edge[-,dotted] (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `positioning` library.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,shapes,positioning}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5cm,sibling distance=50cm,
    semithick]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[
        rounded rectangle,
        fill=red,
        draw=none,
        text=white,
        align=center,
        inner sep=1pt,
        text width=9.5em,
    ]
    \tikzstyle{kernel} = [
        inner sep=1pt,
        node font=\itshape \small,
    ]

    \node[state]    (A)                     {$A(0:DIM\_X, 0)$};
    \node[state]    (B) [below left=of A]   {$A(1, 1)$};
    \node[state]    (C) [below right=of  A] {$A(DIM\_X-2, 1)$};
    \node[state]    (D) [below=of B]        {$A(1, 2)$};
    \node[state]    (E) [right=of D]        {$A(2, 2)$};
    \node[state]    (F) [below=of C]        {$A(DIM\_X-2, 2)$};
    \node[state]    (G) [left=of F]        {$A(DIM\_X-3, 2)$};


    \path (A)   edge node[kernel,swap]      {S(1, 1)}       (B)
                edge node[kernel]   {S(DIM\_X-2, 1)}    (C)
    ;
    \path (B)   edge[-,dotted] (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]